# Unwanted white space below CSS3 gradient when I scroll down

Tags: css, whitespace, gradient

I've been trying all night to find a solution to this problem and haven't been able to find one that works for me.

If your window is big enough, this looks perfect:
http://www.markerin.com/kandk/test.html

but... if your window isn't tall enough, and you scroll, there is white space below the gradient. Is there a way to define #778899 as the default background color and still have the gradient at the top, or to fix the gradient in place? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your color to CSS.

```
html{background-color:#FFF}
```

Replace #FFF with your color

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix will be use `max-height` or/and `min-height`, with harcoded/fixed value (eg:`600px` and `800px` for each) instead `height:100%`, at gradient div class